kerio not working after successful start
have installed and configured Kerio according to its article.
after start it says Starting Kerio Control VPN Client but after i ping 8.8.8.8 it does not respond. i am sure about the kerio server which is working just like a charm in windows. i have had checks for user pass being entered correctly in linux,
do you have any clue to resolve the problem?
the OS is kubuntu 24.04
